# How to Install a 3rd party windows forms control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a WinForms app for my seminar using VS 2010 C# and I'm making a "booking" system. The problem is, the included MonthlyCalendar lacks the option to highlight certain dates, which is just disappointing to me...

Having said that, I decided to look around and found this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar

It looks promising if only I knew how to install it on my Visual Studio 2010, since I see the last update was for v2005 + I don't even know how to install these controls :(

I once installed a 3rd party control but it had a DLL file which I could just drag and drop, and this one doesn't seem to have it...

If someone could lead me through it step by step, I would be most grateful!

Thank you

EDIT:

I just downloaded the .NET 2.0 version and found the DLL file, I dragged and dropped it and it installed, but when I tried to compile it it gives the following errors:

"The error is "The type or namespace name 'Pabo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)."

+

"The referenced assembly "MonthCalendar" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project."

Comment: You will need to change your project's Framework target version to the full version, the Client profile cannot work.

Answer (score 3):

Your project is currently targetting, perhaps, framework 2.0

Right-click on your project file (in solution explorer) and go to properties. Then on the "Application" tab choose Framework 4.0;

To use the 3rd party control do the following

1. Copy your dll next to your project. A sub-folder named "lib" is usually a good name
2. In solution explorer right-click and choose "Add reference". Browse to your dll.
3. Instantiate the class found at the DLL. If you do not know its namespace use the Object Browser right-clicking in your reference.
4. Other alternative is to do it via your toolbox in WinForms 
   In the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar) you provided it says the following

> Like any other .NET control, for using in the IDE, you should add the
>   MonthCalendar control to the Toolbox panel. This can be accomplished
>   by right-clicking on a Toolbox tab and selecting "Add/Remove
>   items...", browsing to the MonthCalendar assembly, and selecting it.
>   This will add the MonthCalendar control to the Toolbox so that it can
>   be dragged/dropped to a Windows Form.